# query to retrieve location , image and name from the given mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Query to retrieve location, image and name from the given mysql database using keyword and location.

I have tried out this query:

```
"select * from tb_user inner join tb_category on tb_user.category_id=tb_category.category_id inner join tb_subcategory on tb_user.subcategory_id=tb_subcategory.subcategory_id inner join tb_location on tb_user.location_id=tb_location.location_id where tb_user.keyword like '%$keyword%' or tb_category.category_name like '%$keyword%' or tb_subcategory.subcategory_name like '%$keyword%' or tb_location.location_name like '%$location%'";
```

[Image Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO5qu.jpg)

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: provide table structure...

Comment: no response for this query its completely blank response

Comment: @GyandeepSharma https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO5qu.jpg

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/rO5qu.jpg this is only one table.. You are using two tables in query tb_category  and tb_user

Comment: @GyandeepSharma https://www.mediafire.com/?cag1oeq1780ywi6

Comment: @GyandeepSharma http://www.mediafire.com/view/cag1oeq1780ywi6/db1.png

Comment: link not working..

Comment: @GyandeepSharma this link is working http://www.mediafire.com/view/cag1oeq1780ywi6/db1.png

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tb_user 
LEFT join tb_category on tb_user.category_id=tb_category.category_id 
LEFT join tb_subcategory on tb_user.subcategory_id=tb_subcategory.subcategory_id 
LEFT join tb_location on tb_user.location_id=tb_location.location_id 
where tb_user.keyword like '%$keyword%' 
or tb_category.category_name like '%$keyword%' 
or tb_subcategory.subcategory_name like '%$keyword%' 
or tb_location.location_name like '%$location%'
```

Try above query.

Comment: @Leechippy `select * from tb_user 
LEFT join tb_category on tb_user.category_id=tb_category.category_id 
LEFT join tb_subcategory on tb_user.subcategory_id=tb_subcategory.subcategory_id 
LEFT join tb_location on tb_user.location_id=tb_location.location_id `

Comment: Try only this query